# discontinuous predictions time series model

Tags: time-series, arima

I am trying to predict patient census by hour for a hospital and the historical data provided to me is in hourly format.  The issue however is that the there is a discontinuous region between the end of the historical data and the beginning of the first time value in the prediction period.  For example, I am given historical data from [1/1/2020,10/15/2021], and from this data my first predicted point forecast is 12/1/2021 at 12AM.  ARIMA models require the first predicted point period t+1 to be the end of the training period at time t, however clearly with this gap region I cannot use ARIMA.  ARIMA also has issues with long-term forecasting at short intervals asymptotic convergence.

In my research in time series modelling I have not encountered this gap issue before, most models will train and then predict the first prediction point as the next point following the end of the training interval.

Comment: I think you should aim to predict for the gap too.  This is quite common (we know what happened in the past up to a point in time and we want some idea of what might happen in the future, but end up also predicting the past after that point in time.

Comment: That could be workable but what model would be used in this case, a 10 week prediction at hourly intervals?